How to use third party python libraries on QGIS plugins?
I am looking for a way to use third party libraries which uses pyproj in QGIS plugins.
I don't want to ask the user to install the library in the system python environment.
Instead, I want to use the library installed in the virtual environment.
My environment
QGIS:

QGIS version 3.36.1-Maidenhead QGIS code branch Release 3.36
Qt version 5.15.13
Python version 3.11.8
Compiled against GDAL/OGR 3.8.4
Running against GDAL/OGR 3.8.5
PROJ version 9.4.0
EPSG Registry database version v11.004 (2024-02-24)
GEOS version 3.12.0-CAPI-1.18.0
Compiled against SQLite 3.45.2
Running against SQLite 3.45.3
PDAL version 2.7.1
PostgreSQL client version 16.2
SpatiaLite version 5.1.0
QWT version 6.2.0
QScintilla2 version 2.14.1
OS version Arch Linux

pyproj: 3.6.1 in the virtual environment and system
The workarounds I have found so far are as follows:
1. Using QGIS Settings (Worked only for some libraries)

Create a virtual environment and install dependencies of the plugin, such as sklearn, in the virtual environment.
Add PYTHONPATH from Settings > Options > System > Environment > PYTHONPATH in QGIS as follows:


Apply: Append
Variable: PYTHONPATH
Value: /path/to/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages

This method worked for some libraries, but it did not work for libraries that use pyproj.
2. Using sys.path.append() (Worked for libraries that use pyproj)
Add following code in the very beginning of the plugin code:
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages')

Problems
In the method 1, if a library uses pyproj, QGIS crashes.
I could use rasterio, scikit-learn, etc which are not using pyproj, but I could not use geopandas.
This is because QGIS uses .venv's pyproj instead of /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproj and that makes crash.
(I don't know why venv's pyproj crashes QGS, though.)
I checked PYTHONPATH with sys.path and I found that the venvs path is inserted before
/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyprojeven I set "Append" in QGIS system environment settings.
In the method 2, venv's path is added to the last of sys.path and it works fine so far.
Problem is that the path to the virtual environment is hardcoded in the plugin code.
This is not a good practice because the path may change depending on the environment.
Questions
Is there a way to use third party libraries which uses pyproj in QGIS plugins without hardcoding the path to the virtual environment?
Similar issues
I already read the following Q&A, but they did not solve my problem.

Installing 3rd party python libraries for QGIS on Windows
I am looking for a way to install required libraries in the virtual environment and use them in QGIS plugins on Linux.

